# A better way to use map to create a new array from array's array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a list of `projects` as followings:

```
projects = [{name: '1',
             agencies: ['USA', 'China']},
            {name: '2',
             agencies: ['Japan', 'Russia']}]
```

I want to get the result `['USA', 'China', 'Japan', 'Russia']`, currently I use the following code, but I would like to know if there is better solution (one line code) using map function:

```
const agencies = [];
projects.forEach((project) =>
        project.agencies.forEach((agency) => {
            agencies.push(agency);
        })
);
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a better way to do already existing code. ask on [codereview.se]

Comment: `const agencies = [].concat(...projects.map(x => x.agencies))` for a one liner.

Comment: This is definitely what I want. Could you post it as answer?

Comment: `var agencies = projects.reduce((arr, p) => [...arr, ...p.agencies], [])` :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple one-liner to accomplish this:

```js
const projects = [{
  name: '1',
  agencies: ['USA', 'China']
}, {
  name: '2',
  agencies: ['Japan', 'Russia']
}]

const agencies = [].concat(...projects.map(x => x.agencies));
console.log(agencies)
```

Answer (score 1):

returned maps, by definition, will always be of the same length as the array used to generate it.

You should probably use reduce instead, to generate a different length array like you want.

try:

```
 projects.reduce((acc, project) => [...acc, ...project.agencies], [])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use destructuring, reduce and concat:

```
  agencies.reduce((res, {agencies}) => res.concat(agencies));
```